# Diferencia entre etc/environment y .bashrc

Tags: java, linux, bash, ubuntu, shell

Tengo una consulta: Que diferencia hay en el archivo oculto **.bashrc** y **etc/environment**?
Se que en etc/environment puedo iniciar ej JAVA_HOME, como tambien MAVEN o APACHE, para que puedan ser accesibles desde todo el sistema
Y por otro lado el archivo .bashrc me sirve para programar bash en el shell de Linux, crear variables globales,exportacion de SDKMAN y otros, pero no entiendo bien la diferenciacion!
Alguien me puede ayudar?

Comment: Bash es uno de los shells (consolas, pues) disponibles; puedes usar zsh, ksh, csh... el `.bashrc` se ejecuta cuando el usuario inicia sesión y usa bash (por eso está en el home de ese usuario); por eso yo no veo tus variables de entorno y por eso los procesos en segundo plano no pueden usar tus variables declaradas ahí. El otro ya viste que aplica para todos.

Comment: .... _y_ si eres un usuario mortal, no vas a poder editar `/etc/environment` ya que probablemente solo el root lo pueda modificar. El `~/.bashrc` es propio y lo puedes modificar a tu gusto.

Comment: @eftshift0 gracias por tu respuesta. Es decir que el .bashrc es para el usuario, y la configuracion de etc/environment es para todos los usuarios. Asi lo tengo que ver? Te explico el contexto: Utilizo mi maquina para programar en java, y soy el root, donde algunas variables como el JAVA_HOME las cargo en etc/environment y otras como los export de JAVA_HOME en etc/environment, y no entiendo porque el entorno de configuracion es asi.

Comment: No tiene que ser así.... en general linux (por su relación con *NIX) es bastaaaaaaante sencillo en este tema. Los procesos (como java... entre muchos otros) leen _variables de entorno_. Los archivos de configuración como los que nombras los leen los intérpretes de comandos en cierto orden..... en tu caso, si eres un solo usuario para el equipo y eres root, puedes hacerlo en cualquier parte.... pero si tuvieras 200 usuarios en el equipo tendrías que considerar que `/etc/environment` afectaría a todo el mundo. ... por ello es que hay varios sitios donde se pueden hacer esos ajustes.

Comment: Ah, entiendo! en mi caso, al ser el unico usuario y root al mismo tiempo es indiferente donde configure las varialbes de entorno, pero si es diferente para muchos usuarios, ya que cada uno tiene su propio .bashrc, pero solo el root es el que controla el unico etc/environment. Es correcto? Disculpa las preguntas es que mi punto debil es la configuracion de entornos con linux y es un mundo nuevo!